# Can someonw assist with JS BodyLoad Error Question

Tags: javascript

help, if anyone can help me figure out why i keep getting bodyLoad error! this is for Javascript, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("conversion_type").onclick = calculate_click;
}


var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function update() {

  if ($("to_celsius").checked = true) {
    document.getElementById("degrees_celcius").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("degrees_celcius").value = ''
  } else($("to_fahrenheit").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("degrees_fahrenheit").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("degrees_fahrenheit").value = ''
  }

  function convert() {
    function convertToC() {
      var fTempVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('degrees_fahrenheit').value);
      var cTempVal = (fTempVal - 32) * (5 / 9);
      document.getElementById('degrees_celcius').value = cTempVal.toFixed(2);
      return false;
    }

    function convertToF() {
      var cTempVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('degrees_celcius').value);
      var fTempVal = (cTempVal * (9 / 5)) + 32;
      document.getElementById('degrees_fahrenheit').value = fTempVal.toFixed(2);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: "bodyLoad error!" ??? What is that? What is the error message? Why is convertToC and convertToF defined inside update? Get a linter installed on your IDE, it will help with a few of these issues.

Comment: @epascarello also `calculate_click` is not defined. And there are syntax errors.

Comment: `else($("to_fahrenheit").checked == true) {` wrong syntax - it should be `else if` ` if ($("to_celsius").checked = true) {` won't cause an error to be thrown but it's a bug `=` is assignment, use `==` or `===` for equality check. Fix the syntax errors in your code.